# error de Thymeleaf java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Tengo un formulario thymeleaf a través del cual tengo que crear un nuevo objeto que va a la bbdd.

Es este.

```
        <form id="formObra" action="#" th:action="@{/newObra}" th:object="${obra_nueva}" method="POST">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <p><b>F&oacute;rmula:</b> <br>Superficie total a construir (m2) * 1100€/m2 * Calidad material (baja/media/alta)</p>
        
                                    <div>
                                        <img th:src="@{/images/obra.png}" style="width: 250px; margin: auto; display: block;"><br><br>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Superficie total a construir (m2):</label><br>
                                        <input th:field="*{superficie}" class="form-control" type="number" id="superficie" />
                                    </div>
        
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="calidad">Calidad material:</label><br>
                                        <input th:field="*{calidad}" type="radio" id="baja"  value="0.8">
                                        <label for="baja">Baja</label><br>
                                        <input th:field="*{calidad}" type="radio" id="media"  value="1">
                                        <label for="media">Media</label><br>
                                        <input th:field="*{calidad}" type="radio" id="alta"  value="1.3">
                                        <label for="alta">Alta</label><br>
                                    </div>
                                    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" id="boton1" href="#">Calcular presupuesto (js)</a>
                                    <br>
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <input class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" type="reset" value="Vaciar campos">
                                        <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit" value="Calcular presupuesto">
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
```

El formulario apunta hacia el controlador /newObra... que está aquí abajo:

```
    @PostMapping("/newObra")
    public String nuevaObra(@Valid ObraNueva obra_nueva, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("obranueva", obra_nueva);
        return "haztupresupuesto";
    }
    obraNuevaService.save(obra_nueva);
    return "redirect:/finishPre";
}
```

Este es el Service:

```
    @Service
    public class ObraNuevaServiceImpl implements ObraNuevaService {
@Autowired
private ObraNuevaRepository obraNuevaRepository;

@Override
public Iterable<ObraNueva> findAll() {
    return obraNuevaRepository.findAll();
}

@Override
public Page<ObraNueva> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
    return obraNuevaRepository.findAll(pageable);
}

@Override
public ObraNueva findById(Long id) {
    Optional<ObraNueva> obraNueva = obraNuevaRepository.findById(id);
    if (obraNueva.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return obraNueva.get();
}

@Override
public ObraNueva save(ObraNueva obraNueva) {
    return obraNuevaRepository.save(obraNueva);
}

@Override
public void deleteById(Long id) {
    obraNuevaRepository.deleteById(id);
}

@Override
public boolean existsByReferencia(String referencia) {
    return obraNuevaRepository.existsByReferencia(referencia);
}

@Override
public ObraNueva findByReferencia(String referencia) {
    return obraNuevaRepository.findByReferencia(referencia);
}
    }
```

Y esto va hacia el repositorio.

```
    public interface ObraNuevaRepository extends JpaRepository<ObraNueva, Long>{
        boolean existsByReferencia(String referencia);

        ObraNueva findByReferencia(String referencia);
    }
```

Esta es la clase de dominio ObraNueva:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="obra_nueva")
    public class ObraNueva {
public static final String PREFIJO = "OBN";

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id_obra_nueva;
    
@OneToOne(mappedBy="obra")
private Presupuesto presupuesto;

protected String referencia;

@NotNull(message="Debes introducir un numérico")
@Min(value=0,message="Debe ser mayor a 0")
private int superficie;

@NotNull(message="Introduce al menos uno de los tres valores indicados")
private double calidad;

public ObraNueva() {
    super();
}

public ObraNueva(String referencia,
        @NotNull(message = "Debes introducir un numérico") @Min(value = 0, message = "Debe ser mayor a 0") int superficie,
        @NotNull(message = "Introduce al menos uno de los tres valores indicados") double calidad) {
    super();
    this.referencia = referencia;
    this.superficie = superficie;
    this.calidad = calidad;
}

public ObraNueva(long id_obra_nueva, String referencia,
        @NotNull(message = "Debes introducir un numérico") @Min(value = 0, message = "Debe ser mayor a 0") int superficie,
        @NotNull(message = "Introduce al menos uno de los tres valores indicados") double calidad) {
    super();
    this.id_obra_nueva = id_obra_nueva;
    this.referencia = referencia;
    this.superficie = superficie;
    this.calidad = calidad;
}

public long getId_obra_nueva() {
    return id_obra_nueva;
}

public void setId_obra_nueva(long id_obra_nueva) {
    this.id_obra_nueva = id_obra_nueva;
}

public String getReferencia() {
    return PREFIJO + this.id_obra_nueva;
}

public int getSuperficie() {
    return superficie;
}

public void setSuperficie(int superficie) {
    this.superficie = superficie;
}

public double getCalidad() {
    return calidad;
}

public void setCalidad(double calidad_material) {
    this.calidad = calidad_material;
}

}
```

La cosa es que me aparece el error siguiente:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/haztupresupuesto.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1103) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1077) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:372) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:192) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1415) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1159) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1098) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:537) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:631) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring6.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "haztupresupuesto" - line 172, col 43)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393) ~[attoparser-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257) ~[attoparser-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 89 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring6.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "haztupresupuesto" - line 172, col 43)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:117) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:260) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:256) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:169) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:104) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleStandaloneElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:79) ~[attoparser-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:241) ~[attoparser-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:327) ~[attoparser-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseStandaloneElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:96) ~[attoparser-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:706) ~[attoparser-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301) ~[attoparser-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 91 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'obra_nueva' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:153) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:926) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:232) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:306) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:253) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:227) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:174) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 104 common frames omitted
```

Ando un poco perdido utilizando thymeleaf y spring boot xd, ¿como puedo hacer para corregir este error?

Comment: Agregá el método del controller donde llamás al formulario de Thymeleaf para ver qué puede estar faltando.

Comment: Okey, ya resolví este error :) en el formulario le enviaba el objeto por thymeleaf obra_nueva cuando en mi controlador este mismo parámetro lo recogía como obra nueva. Fallo de nomenclatura